# Creating a count-by-count matrix

Tags: java

I need to create a count-by-count matrix of asterisks and percent signs, alternating by row. The user is asked to input a number and the number of asterisks, percent signs, and rows depend on the user input.

Example:
if the user input is 5 the output will look like this...

```
* * * * *
% % % % %
* * * * *
% % % % %
* * * * *
```

I am trying to use a for loop and I have it programmed so that it will print out 5 asterisks wide and 5 tall, thus making a little square, but I don't know how to get every other row printing out as percent signs.

Here is my code so far : My question is under 7c.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   System.out.println("************** Question 1 *************************\n");
   System.out.println("*\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 2 *************************\n");
   char perc = '%';
   char ast = '*';
   System.out.println(ast+"\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 3 *************************\n");
   for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
   }
   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("************** Question 4 *************************");
   System.out.println();
   for (int i =0; i<=9; i++)
   {
       System.out.println(ast);
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("***************************************************");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("************** Question 5 *************************");
   Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter a positive number :");
   int count = keyboardInput.nextInt();
   for (int i=0; i<=count;i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
   }
   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 6 *************************\n");
   for (int i=1;i<=count;i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
      if (i%5==0)
      {
         System.out.println();
      }
   }   
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7a ************************\n");  
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7b ************************\n");
   for (int h=0;h<count;h++)
   {
      for (int w=0;w<count;w++)
      {
          System.out.print(ast);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.println(); 
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7c ************************\n");
   for (int h=0; h<count; h++)
   {
      for(int w=0; w<count; w++)
      {
         System.out.print(ast);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the row number is divisible by two, and choose the character based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java pseudo code
---------------------
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{

String x;
if(i%2==0)
x="*";
else
x="%"

for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
System.out.println(x+"\t");
}
System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator and ternary expressions form a common and powerful team for something like this:

```
String sym = (i % 2) ? "%" : "*";
```

Your code might look something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    String sym = (i % 2) = "%" : "*";
    for(j=0; j<count; j++)
    {
        // Up to you
    }
}
```

(`char` is probably a more appropriate type for `sym`, however)

Answer (score 0):

The print statement should act conditionally.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<= count; i++)
   {
     if(i%2 == 0)
         System.out.print(ast);
     else
       System.out.print(perc );
   }
```